# How to use href attribute in a link tag accurately in android?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

Im trying to link a css file to my html file in android, but when I check the style, it is not being loaded and applied.

I have the css and html files in the same folder, and I have tried with absolute and relative paths, with apostrophes and quotes, but nothing works.

I have tested by providing a link to a stylesheet on the internet.

It works with https, but it does not with files.

I am testing with a Xiaomi Redmi note 5 running Android 9, no frameworks, just loading the HTML file directly into the browser.

HTML FILE:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS E</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="par1">
        Sample web page
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE:

```css
.par1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

I've tried additional paths including `./main.css`, `main.css`, `file://sdcard/html/main.css` and more.

When I load the file in the browser, the search bar shows the next:

content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/HTML/main.html

Comment: Can you add the following details:

1. What Android version are you running

2.  Are you using any special frameworks (it feels like you are, so the framework name would be helpful)?

3. Do you get any error logs or messages when debugging this?

Comment: Im using android 9 pkg 1. No frameworks. I just test it openning the html file directly in the browser.

Comment: upload that html page code @JuanAngel

Comment: `href='https...."`: And this starts with `single quote (')` and end with `double quotes(")` how?

Comment: Sorry. Quotes are wrong in the question.

Comment: Page code added

Comment: if you are having only few css then u add inside the html file itself internally.@JuanAngel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css file is in correct place just load html file from this url:

```
file:///sdcard/HTML/main.html
```

Comment: I don't know why the File explorer was making the browser loads the html from a different directory. When I set that path, it perfectly works.

THANKS A LOT.

Comment: File explorer made temprary file in that folder but `main.css` is found in only Html folder so that is 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, keep the CSS file in assets folder.
Then, write the following code in html file as-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/main.css" />
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Im not using frameworks, so I dont have any folder or directory called "android_asset" ...

Comment: @Juan Angel because of your [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag people are confused.

Comment: @Rk003 ... tag deleted